# How to get on_press to work in custom buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a custom button that will change colors when pressed (actually changing the tint on an image) and I can't even get the on_press to work correctly.  The app runs, but pressing the button gives the error: "Attribute Error: 'ImageButton' object has no attribute 'change_color'"

The python file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ImageButton():
    def change_color(self):
        print("Success!")

class TestName(App):
    def build(self):
        return tester

tester = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestName().run()
```

The Kivy file:

```
Container:

<Container>:
    BoxLayout:
        ImageButton:
            source: "emptybox.png"


<ImageButton@Button>:
    source: None
    on_press: root.change_color()

    Image:
        source: root.source
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background or text color of `ImageButton`?

Comment: I'm going to create a transparent canvas over the button when it's pressed that makes it look darker.

Comment: I just created an answer, in this case I change the background using a transparent image. However, if you have a problem please comment and I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- First, `build` method returns `tester` (the output of `Builder.load_file`).
- On the other hand, your `ImageButton` class in .py file should inherit from `kivy.uix.button.Button`.

I do not know what "color" you want to change, I leave you an example where you change background color when pressed :

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from random import random


kv_text = '''
<Container>:
    BoxLayout:
        ImageButton:
            source: "emptybox.png"


<ImageButton@Button>:
    source: None
    on_press: self.change_color()

    Image:
        source: root.source
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size

'''


class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ImageButton(Button):
    def change_color(self):
        self.background_color = (random(), random(), random(),  1)

class TestName(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_text)
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestName().run()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple, I forgot to inherit from Button!  Thank you so much!  And I love your example. :)